# first line indent of List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I need to add the word `Figure` and `Table` to list of tables and figures. I have the code below to obtain this but my code applies extra space to the first line of the text in the list of tables. All the lines should have no indent.

There are some answers about this topic but they are based on `tocloft`. I have a thesis format, so I need a solution without `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\hspace{-1.5em}Table~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%

    \section{A section}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{centering}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                $T_1$ & $T_2$\\
                \hline 
                $75^\circ$ & $25^\circ$\\
            \end{tabular}
            \par\end{centering}
        \caption{\lipsum[4]\label{tab_ref}}       
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason the `\label` is inside the `\caption`?

Comment: For this example, no. But i use `\label` in my main document, of course.

Comment: Why do you think that an answer that works with the `article` class would work with your unidentified thesis format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following helps:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{4em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\oldnumberline{Table #1}}
\listoftables

\section{A section}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    $T_1$ & $T_2$\\
    \hline 
    $75^\circ$ & $25^\circ$
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\lipsum[4]\label{tab_ref}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]